# Change how Explorer sorts files with number in name

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, sorting

In Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008, if files have only number in filename, Explorer sorts them by the number.

[image]

How can I change this sort to trully alphabetic, ie.:

```
108
1110
188
439
455
```

etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Dave: I don't recommend telling people to edit the Registry unless as a last resort when there's no easier/better way.

@Tschareck: Here's what you can do:

1. Type *gpedit.msc* in the Start menu's search box and then press Enter.
2. Navigate to *User Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components*, then select *Windows Explorer* in the left pane of the Group Policy editor.
3. Double-click *Turn off numerical sorting in Windows Explorer* in the Settings section of the Group Policy editor.
4. Select Enable and then click OK to save the changes.

Answer (score 1):

To change this behavior open your registry and find the key below.

```
User Key: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
Explorer]
System Key: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
Explorer]
Value Name: NoStrCmpLogical
Data Type: REG_DWORD (DWORD Value)
Value Data: (1 = Windows 2000 method)
```

Create a new DWORD value named "NoStrCmpLogical" and set it to "1" to use the Windows 2000 sorting method.

Comment: I prefer the registry method. Unfortunately, Windows still sorts in its "special" way when using "Sort by Type". Also, on my machine at least, I can't modify my `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` key.