Windows 10 folders sorted incorrectly in File Explorer
Imagine a folder that has the following subfolders
we207ill_241217
we20wox2_241217
we21jheq_241217

If sorted by name in ascending order you would expect them to be sorted as above.
File Explorer sorts them like this:
we20wox2_241217
we21jheq_241217
we207ill_241217

Regardless of how you weigh numbers vs. letter, 20 should come before 21, no?
What am I missing?
To test this out locally run
md we20wox2_241217 && md we21jheq_241217 && md we207ill_241217

Interestingly running ls in the directory shows
we207ill_241217  we20wox2_241217  we21jheq_241217


If I had to guess it's grouping the numbers somehow. So 20 < 21 < 207
Unfortunately this bleeds over into the sorting for something like VSCode where I'm expecting less "magic"

Does this answer your question? https://superuser.com/questions/536438/weird-directory-sort-order?rq=1
