# Permanently configure "Sort By" date for external drive in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I frequently connect my Lollipop Android phone to my Windows 10 through a USB to transfer documents.

I go to [Phone] > WhatsApp > Media > Documents, only to find that the documents are NOT sorted by date modified.

This happens every time I unplug and plug my device back.

Is there any permanent way to set the sorting rule?

Comment: Please let me know if there's something else I needed to add in my question to make it complete. Thank you!

Comment: I read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1096697/how-to-sort-by-date-modified-ascending-always-in-windows) but it looks like it is valid for only for those hard drives which pre-exist/are permanently attached to the computer.

Comment: Here's one with a Group Policy method, https://superuser.com/questions/1065671/is-there-a-way-to-fix-the-sort-by-name-in-windows-10-file-explorer ... Give it a try and maybe it'll do the job but easy enough for you to test if you can and have a version of Windows 10 that has gpedit.msc.

Comment: Lollipop is an outdated OS for Android phones. Several generations behind the current OS. Lollipop had security and keyboard issues.

Comment: @ITSnuggles Thanks for your help. I checked it out but sorry it has to do with another sorting rule (*sort numerically 111<22<3*) and nothing to do with permanently sorting by date.

Comment: @Sparky256 I understand your concern. My phone works very well otherwise. I wonder if the same problem persists in newer android versions, though I don't have a newer android to test this.