# Differences in A-Z sorting in Explorer vs Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-explorer, sorting

I have a list of files in Windows Explorer sorted ascending by name

```
3a.txt
6a.txt
10a.txt
```

In Excel I have the names of these files in a column, I sort them A-Z and except them to be the same as the order of the files in Explorer, however this is not the case:

```
Sheet1: SORTED A-Z
10a.txt
3a.txt
6a.txt
```

I do not mind whichever sorting is used however I need the sorting to be consistent across both programs. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [windows 7 - Change how Explorer sorts files with number in name - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/476086/change-how-explorer-sorts-files-with-number-in-name)

Comment: [The sort order for files and folders whose names contain numerals is different in Windows Vista, Windows XP, and Windows Server 2003 than it is in Windows 2000](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/319827/the-sort-order-for-files-and-folders-whose-names-contain-numerals-is-d)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change how Explorer sorts files with number in name](https://superuser.com/questions/476086/change-how-explorer-sorts-files-with-number-in-name)

Comment: Use numbers with a FIXED digit count; 001.txt instead of 1.txt - the easiest way to avoid this present-all-over problem. Related problem, solution: Use YYYY-MM-DD formatted dates.

Comment: alternatively use `dir /o:n` in cmd or `ls` in powershell to get the files in lexicographic order which is similar to Excel, no need to change the sorting order in Explorer

Comment: You could investigate writing something in VBA using the [StrCmpLogicalW function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strcmplogicalw) to get the same sort order as Windows Explorer uses.

Answer (score 3):

Excel sorts in simple alphabetical order, while Windows Explorer uses numerical
sorting. So Explorer will cleverly sort `file9` before `file10`, while Excel
will do the opposite.

As solution, you may either make all the numbers of your file names to be of
the same length, meaning `file09` and `file10`, or disable numerical sorting
in Explorer.

To disable numerical sorting in Explorer:

- Start the Local Group Policy Editor from the Start menu or run `gpedit.msc`
- Navigate to
  *User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > File Explorer*
- Double-click *Turn off numerical sorting in File Explorer* on the right
- Select *Enable*
- Click OK to save the changes
- Logout and back in to apply the changes.

For more information see the article
[How to Enable or Disable Numerical Sorting in File Explorer in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/91417-enable-disable-numerical-sorting-file-explorer-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: Is there a way to enable numerical sorting in excel?