# sort by name in Explorer doesn't fully sort by name

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I have about 1,500 XML files in a folder. I'm going a little bit crazy because when I sort by name it sort of looks like it's sorted by name, but if you scroll around you can see it isn't fully.

The top of the list looks OK:

[image]

...but scrolling down further you see this:

[image]

I've already checked to make sure those are zeros and not o's, and they're not. I've also checked that there aren't phantomn spaces at the beginning of some filenames, and there aren't. What is going on??

Comment: It is sorting them numerically, whereas 010 is still considered 10 and should come after 9.

Comment: I don't think that's it. The screenshot doesn't show everything but at first it goes 00... 0a... 0b... ... 1a... 1b... etc. Then once that sequence finishes in the second screenshot you have 9f... and suddenly 010. Also I've never known Windows to sort things numerically.

Comment: By default there is a GPO setting for file explorer that is set to numerical sorting. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/415629/sort-order-in-windows-explorer)

Comment: Might shed some lights as well: `@("9fd9aedcc9c79dc1658bfe597299f95","010c568209a689f8cd4005a83c2feeae") | Sort-Object | ForEach-Object {$_.Length, $_}` in PowerShell