# Ordering files alphabetically is not respected in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-7, sorting, ordering

I've a folder with a file list.

All files have the same root name but change in order on its refere date, as follow:

This is my wished alfabetically order:

- MyName - 202003.pdf
- MyName - 202006.pdf
- MyName - 20200708.pdf <------
- MyName - 202009.pdf
- MyName - 202011.pdf
- MyName - 202012.pdf
- MyName - 202101.pdf
- MyName - 202102.pdf

But in my folder the order is:

- MyName - 202003.pdf
- MyName - 202006.pdf
- MyName - 202009.pdf
- MyName - 202011.pdf
- MyName - 202012.pdf
- MyName - 202101.pdf
- MyName - 202102.pdf
- MyName - 20200708.pdf <------

I've already checked the right configuration about the folder order (Name - ascending) but the last file is in wrong position.

You have notice about this bug? I can fix it?

Comment: See here https://superuser.com/questions/415629/sort-order-in-windows-explorer

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Good find! Next time please flag the question as a duplicate. It will automatically post a comment like spikey_richie's.